# Could we add a prompt to upvote questions that have upvoted answers?

Tags: feature-request

It's interesting that we often have answers that are voted much higher than the question that prompted them.

In the name of encouraging questions, could we add a prompt to MP&T that suggests the user upvote the question after they upvote an answer for that question?

Answer (score 10):

This doesn't make much sense to me since the quality of the question asked and the quality of the answer given are not always the same. There are some really good questions that have ok answers and there are ok questions that have great answers. Just because one gets an up vote it doesn't mean the other should.

One example I'll give is we tend to get a few of questions that while not duplicates are concepts that are brought up on the site a lot and are explained over and over again. I typically won't up vote the question, but if there is a good answer there I typically will up vote it.

The pattern you noticed is common on all SE sites. The simple reason is even the most intriguing questions don't stack up well to the knowledge one can gain from an amazing answer. This can even be seen in the weight of the up votes with an up voted answer being worth double the value of an up voted question.

Another thing to note is on our higher voted questions and answers some of the votes come from the users of other SE sites that see the question in the hot network questions. They typically read the questions and answers and up vote what they want to and go back to their typical SE site and don't see the question or the site again for a while. Because of this,  they will take the typical voting pattern on there site and apply it here.

Comment: This sums it up perfectly. +1